# excel macros checking for value and moving to cell below

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

so Ive got programming knowledge but i need help with excel

i need to create a macro that checks for a specific value in a cell (e.g. begins with "01A") and if it finds it to check the cell underneath it for the same value. It should keep doing that until the value changes. I would also like it to calculate how many times it found that specific value (counta())

here is an example i would use if i were to do something similar in c

```
if (value = 01a){    

amount ++

value + 1

}
```

any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

If you need to search only the first occurrance in a range, use:

```
Public Function FoundRec(Str As String, x As Range) As Integer
    Application.Volatile

    Dim i As Integer
    Set c = x.Find(Str, after:=x.Item(x.Rows.Count), LookIn:=xlValues)
    If c Is Nothing Then
        FoundRec = 0
        Exit Function
    End If

    For i = 1 To 9999
        If c.Offset(i, 0).Value <> c.Value Then Exit For
    Next

    FoundRec = i
End Function
```

This function search the string Str in the range x :

```
=FoundRec("01A";A2:A16)
```

Return 0 if don't found.
If you need to search in the other occurrance, you can use:

```
Public Function FoundRecR(Str As String, x As Range, StartR As Integer) As Single
    Application.Volatile

    Dim i, e As Integer
    Dim xx As Range

    Set xx = x.Item(1)
    For e = 1 To StartR
        If e = 1 Then
            Set c = x.Find(Str, after:=x.Item(x.Rows.Count), LookIn:=xlValues)
        Else
            Set c = x.Find(Str, after:=xx, LookIn:=xlValues)
        End If
        If xx.Row > c.Row Then  ' Restart to Find ...
            FoundRecR = -1
            Exit Function
        End If
        If c Is Nothing Then
            FoundRecR = 0
            Exit Function
        End If

        For i = 1 To 9999
            If c.Offset(i, 0).Value <> c.Value Then Exit For
        Next
        Set xx = c.Offset(i - 1, 0)
    Next

    FoundRecR = i
End Function
```

The function search the occurrance StartR of the string Str in the range x:

```
=FoundRecR("01A";A2:A16;1)
```

Return 0 if don't found and -1 if the occurrance it's to high (no other occurrance).
The After parameter it's necessary to force Excel to start from the first cell of the range, otherwise Excel ignore...